# How to assign value and sum up rows in R in a simpler way?

Tags: r, replace, sum

I run my code and I get a data frame

```
            V1 V2 V3 V4
1        CCL5  P  0  0
2      CYP2A6  M  A  A
3      CYP2E1  P  A  P
4        DDR1  P  0  P
5       EPHB3  A  P  A
6       ESRRA  A  A  P
7      GUCA1A  A  0  0
8       HSPA6  A  0  A
9  NCRNA00152  A  0  0
10       PAX8  P  0  P
11     PTPN21  P  0  A
12       RFC2  P  0  P
13     SCARB1  P  P  P
14       THRA  P  0  A
15     TTLL12  P  0  P
16       UBA7  P  0  P
17      WFDC2  P  0  0
```

To process the data frame further I run this code

```
    replace <- function(d1)
    {
      rows=nrow(d1)
      cols=ncol(d1)
      for(i in 1:rows)
      {
        for (j in 2:cols)
        {
          if (d1[i,j]=="P")
            d1[i,j] = 2
          else if(d1[i,j]=="A")
            d1[i,j]= -2
          else if(d1[i,j]=="M")
            d1[i,j]= 0
        }
      }

      for(i in 1:rows)
      {
        j=2
        sum=0
        while(j<=cols)
        {
          sum1=as.numeric(d1[i,j])
          sum=sum+sum1
          j=j+1 
        }
        d1[i,cols+1]=sum
        if(sum > 0)
          d1[i,cols+2]="P"
        else if(sum < 0)
          d1[i,cols+2]="A"
        else if(sum==0)
          d1[i,cols+2]="0"
      }
      return(d1)
    }
replace(d1)
```

so that my data frame should look like this. I replace P by 2 and A by -2 and M by 0 and then sum up in other column . In 5th column if value is positive than P in last column , if negative then A and for 0 its 0.

```
           V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1        CCL5  2  0  0  2  P
2      CYP2A6  0 -2 -2 -4  A
3      CYP2E1  2 -2  2  2  P
4        DDR1  2  0  2  4  P
5       EPHB3 -2  2 -2 -2  A
6       ESRRA -2 -2  2 -2  A
7      GUCA1A -2  0  0 -2  A
8       HSPA6 -2  0 -2 -4  A
9  NCRNA00152 -2  0  0 -2  A
10       PAX8  2  0  2  4  P
11     PTPN21  2  0 -2  0  0
12       RFC2  2  0  2  4  P
13     SCARB1  2  2  2  6  P
14       THRA  2  0 -2  0  0
15     TTLL12  2  0  2  4  P
16       UBA7  2  0  2  4  P
17      WFDC2  2  0  0  2  P
```

I think my code is very long to do this simple task. Is there any way to make it pretty simple. Thanks a lot.

Edited: in my data frame there may be more than 200 or more columns.

Comment: the first part : `myrep<-sapply(1:nrow(d1),function(i){
sapply(2:ncol(d1),function(j){
  ifelse(d1[i,j]=="P",2,ifelse(d1[i,j]=="A",-2,0))
})
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach based on named vectors:

```
m  <- c(P=2, A=-2, '0'=0, M=0)
m.back <- c(P=1, A=-1, '0'=0)

d1$V5 <- with(d1, m[V2] + m[V3] + m[V4])
d1$V6 <- names(m.back)[match(sign(d1$V5), m.back)]
```

where `d1` is your data set.

**[UPDATE]** If you'd like to sum all columns of your data set except the first one:

```
m  <- c(P=2, A=-2, '0'=0, M=0)
m.back <- c(P=1, A=-1, '0'=0)

converted <- m[unlist(d1[,-1])]

d1$sum <- rowSums(matrix(converted,ncol=ncol(d1)-1))

d1$symbolic.sum <- names(m.back)[match(sign(d1$sum), m.back)]
```

Comment: in my data frame if I don't know the column number say some 200 or more columns then how to do.

Comment: it seems to serve the purpose ...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `df` is your data.frame. The first thing is to convert all `factors` in `character`. Then replace with the wanted values  - I do this with a deep functional programming approach, so no side effect on your `df` :) and convert wanted columns to `numeric`:

```
library(functional)

df[] = lapply(df, as.character)

f   = function(df, u, target) {df[df==u]=target; df}
fs  = Map(function(x,y) Curry(f, u=x, target=y), c('P','A','M'),c('2','-2','0'))
df1 = Reduce(Compose, fs)(df)

df1 = transform(df1, V5=rowSums(apply(df1[,2:4], 2, as.numeric)))
transform(df1, V6=ifelse(df1$V5>0, 'P', ifelse(df1$V5<0,'A','0')))
#      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1   CCL5  2  0  0  2  P
#2 CYP2A6  0 -2 -2 -4  A
#3 CYP2E1  2 -2  2  2  P
#4   DDR1  2  0  2  4  P
```

**Data**

```
df = data.frame(V1=c("CCL5","CYP2A6","CYP2E1","DDR1"), V2=c("P",'M','P','P'), V3=c('0','A','A','0'), V4=c('0','A','P','P'))
```

Comment: Will it be efficient in terms of time . Does your code take less time then mine

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
d1[d1 == "P"] <- 2
d1[d1 == "A"] <- -2
d1[d1 == "M"] <- 0
```

Then you can take rowsums of d1[, 2:5] and place then in the last column.

And finally replace again with

```
d1[,6][d1[,6] > 0] <- "P"
d1[,6][d1[,6] < 0] <- "A"
```